# Divide and conquer recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I have divide and conquer problem and below is the recurrence relation for it
$$\begin{align}t (n) &= a\cdot t (n/4) + O (n^2/\log(n)) + O(n^2)\\
t(n) &= a\cdot t (n/4) + O(n^2)
\end{align}$$
I solved this recurrence for different values of $a$. These are the solutions below
$$ =\begin{cases}O(n^2),&\text{ for }a = 8\\
O(n^2 \log(n)),&\text{ for }a = 16\\
O(n^5/2),&\text{ for }a=32
\end{cases}$$

Do these solution always apply if $n$ is not power of $4$ and how can I justify it?

Comment: Is the last case n^(5/2)?

Comment: I see two recurrence relations !?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define first where the recursion ends. And what t(n/4) means if n is not a multiple of 4.

The likely outcome will be that t(n) for 4^k < n < 4^(k+1) is between t(4^k) and t(4^(k+1)).

Answer (score -1):

We can use **[Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html)** to solve this :

If a **Recurrence Relation** is of the Form

### $$T(n)=aT\bigg(\frac{n}{b}\bigg)+{n^k}({\log(n)})^p$$

Then, as per **[Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=FOR%20DIVIDING%20FUNCTIONS%C2%A0)**, we have **Six Conditions** depending on value of $a,b,k$ and $p$

- If $\log_ba>k$
  Answer is $\theta(n^{\log_ba})$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p>-1$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^{p+1})$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p=-1$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}\log\log n)$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p<-1$
  Answer is $\theta(n^k)$
- If $\log_ba<k$ and $p\geqslant0$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^p)$
- If $\log_ba<k$ and $p<0$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k})$

In any problem, our main motive is to find $a,b,k$ and $p$.

**In Given Problem**
$b=4$
$k=2$
$p=0$

1. If $a=8$, $\log_48 = 1.5$ which is less than $k$, and $p\geq0$

   Therefore, Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^p)$. Putting Values
   **$$\theta(n^2)$$**
2. If $a=16$, $\log_416 = 2$ which is equal to $k$, and $p>-1$

   Therefore, Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^{p+1})$. Putting Values
   **$$\theta({n^2}{\log n})$$**
3. If $a=32$, $\log_432 = 2.5$ which is  greater than $k$

   Therefore, Answer is $\theta(n^{\log_ba})$. Putting Values
   **$$\theta({n^{5/2}})$$**

**Thus, obtained solutions are Correct!**

- Since, we are finding *"Time Complexity"*, and not *"Solution of Recurrence Relation"*, the asymptotic analysis of the Recurrence Relation is correct whatever may be the value of $n$.
- Moreover, this entire result can be justified by [Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=.-,But%2C%20why%20it%20works%E2%9D%94,-The%20approach%20was). The Theorem *[means, it has been [mathematically proved](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=.-,But%2C%20why%20it%20works%E2%9D%94,-The%20approach%20was)]* provides a crisp method for finding Time Complexity with help of Recurrence Relation.

Comment: Are you affiliated to ediscretestructures blogspot com? It is distractive to put FOUR links to the same web address (I clicked each one of them). By the way, could you please address user's question "Do these solution always apply if $n$ is not power of 4 and how can I justify it?" directly? The OP knows Master theorem, apparently. By the way, this question is about asymptotic analysis, not "time complexity".

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks for highlighting. Yes, it's true that FOUR links are there, but they were of DIFFERENT SECTIONS of page. When I posted they were redirecting to different sections. But currently they are not. If it's distractive, you can edit answer to remove links. I have tried to address answer of actual question in last two points.  And since Recurrence was labelled as $t(n)$ , I assumed it is of Time Complexity also.